# Youtube's large player button doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: windows-7, firefox, youtube

When I click the button below, the video player doesn't expand.
I am using Firefox 8.0.1 Windows 7 64-bit. Any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

Note: I do not experience this problem in my other browsers like Safari and IE.

Comment: Have you tried disabling your plugins to see if one of them is causing it?

Comment: I tried disabling all plugins/add-ons then re-enabling, it worked for a while but problem came back next day.

Comment: Do you have any plugins that affect youtube?

Comment: none directly related to youtube.

Comment: here are my current: plugins/extensions: http://i.imgur.com/IOQGI.png

Note: It's working fine again now, I didn't do anything but I'm sure it will come back soon :-)

Comment: The only one I can think of that could affect Youtube is DownThemAll. You might try disabling that for a few days and seeing if the problem goes away.

Comment: Running **Firefox 8.0.1 Windows 7 64-bit** here also, and it works.

Comment: I would like to mention that I am also having this problem.  I tried disabling all addons and plugins and it still doesn't work.  Works on Chrome though so I'm pretty sure it's not Youtube...

Comment: Apparently, other people also experience the same problems even on Chrome: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?fid=7354c37da855fc180004b46d259e6d71&hl=en

Comment: Hmm Interesting, does clicking on timestamps in people's comments work for you? Like clicking on '1:20' should skip to that time in the video but it doesn't work either.

Comment: yes the timestamp too doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to clear your cookies from Youtube.com

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=2ea00da96a8a3882&hl=en

If you got it working, most likely you cleared your history and cookies or they got reset.  Deleting the cookies from Youtube.com fixed the problem for me.

I recently used the Firefox add-on FEBE to restore all my settings/passwords/addons from a previous install of Windows (upgraded some hardware).  I believe there was some issue with restoring the cookies from a previous build.

Comment: I tried clearing cookies and it worked! Thanks

Comment: Hmm.. Well apparently it keeps coming back. I already cleared cookies twice. Worked for a while then problem's back. Even if I don't do anything just watch videos it comes back after a while.

Comment: What addons and plugins do you have installed?

Comment: These: http://i.imgur.com/IOQGI.png

Answer (score 3):

Cookie deletion didnt work for me. tried other things, read, watched videos, tried again, nothing!

Then, I simply went into my add-ons, and disabled some. Still nothing. Then disabled more. Nothing. Of course, Firefox wanted to re-start itself after each round of disabling add-ons, I should add. Then disabled a few more, and it was fixed.

Then I, of course, re-enabled everything I had disabled, came back to youtube, and now the "small player" option doesnt work. Which is fine with me.

So it appears that one, or more, of my add-ons was interfering with THE OPTION BUTTONS for the large and small player, instead of something more complicated which was limiting the size of the player.

Try that, those of you running FF 15.0.1 and running Windows XP Pro SP3.

Comment: Flashblock is the culprit for me, and as of version 1.5.16 (nightly) the problem still persist. Disabling Flashblock makes the buttons work as they should, for me anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I have the FlashBlock add-on installed in Firefox, and clicking "Allow Flash from this site" on the FlashBlock icon in the toolbar and reloading the page solved it for me. No need to disable the entire add-on.

An added bonus: After selecting large player on YouTube, I then disallowed Flash from YouTube in FlashBlosk, reloaded the page and now the player is stuck in Large mode, just the way I want it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me!

I have Ad Block Plus as an extension, and you have to add an exception in AdBlock settings for youtube.com or s.ytimg.com and the issue should be gone. You should have full control over the video and it's options.

Hope this helps.